# Kubernetes - Communication between services using https

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 services deployed in Kubernetes both should be ssl end to end.

1. Web based applications
2. Business service

Web based Application needs sticky session, so its been exposed using Ingress.

```
Web Based Application ---> Ingress(HTTPS) --> Service(ClusterIP) --> Pods(Enabled SSL)
Business Service --> Service(Load Balancer/Cluster IP) -->  Pods(Enables SSL)
```

Here the requirement is Business Service should be accessible only by Web App and not by anyone else. With just HTTP, I can have ClusterIP and restrict business service access using Network policies. But, I need SSL from WebApp to Business service. It throws error("Domain name not matching") if I access using https. Is there any better way for this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you access the *Business Service* from your *Web Based App*. You should use DNS service discovery here, see [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)
 and your https-certificate must reflect this **URL**, you could use a **self-signed certificated** here.

Comment: Self signed cert is not an option for me.

Comment: Am using DNS discovery, but using https throws domain name match error as the certain are not self signed.